# Getting bad request response error in Tumblr api /posts endpoint

Tags: python, python-requests, tumblr, hmacsha1, oauth-1.0a

I am using python for making a post request on tumblr /posts endpoint but getting an error response.
This is the code. Tumblr api use oauth1 authentication.

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

consumer_key = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000"
consumer_secret = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000"
token = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000"
token_secret = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000"

oauth = OAuth1(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=token,
    resource_owner_secret=token_secret,
    signature_method='HMAC-SHA1'
)

url = 'https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/aisamarsha-blog.tumblr.com/posts'

params = {
    'type': 'photo',
    'state': 'published',
    'tags': 'tag1, tag2, tag3',
    'content': [
        {
            'type': 'image',
            'url': 'http://69.media.tumblr.com/b06fe71cc4ab47e93749df060ff54a90/tumblr_nshp8oVOnV1rg0s9xo1_250.jpg',
            'caption': 'This is the caption for image1'
        },
        {
            'type': 'image',
            'url': 'http://69.media.tumblr.com/b06fe71cc4ab47e93749df060ff54a90/tumblr_nshp8oVOnV1rg0s9xo1_250.jpg',
            'caption': 'This is the caption for image2'
        },
        {
            'type': 'image',
            'url': 'http://69.media.tumblr.com/b06fe71cc4ab47e93749df060ff54a90/tumblr_nshp8oVOnV1rg0s9xo1_1280.jpg',
            'caption': 'This is the caption for image3'
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(url, auth=oauth, json=params)

print(response.json())
```

I want to post blog with multple images, tags and caption on tumblr.

Comment: What happens when you use `data=params` instead of `json=params`?

Comment: it give unauthorized error response
{'meta': {'status': 401, 'msg': 'Unauthorized'}, 'response': [], 'errors': [{'title': 'Unauthorized', 'code': 1016, 'detail': 'Unable to 
authorize'}]}

Comment: Ah okay, I think that gets you closer. I think you might have to try and go through the OAuth flow to get proper credentials. Try the [OAuth2 steps](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#oauth2-authorization).